# CGAffineTransform rotation causes a switch between width and height when defining SnapKit values

Tags: ios, autolayout, snapkit

I am fairly used to using SnapKit, but I am not sure how to solve this issue.

This is what my current UI looks like:

[image]

To achieve this, I do:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

 regionsPicker.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalToSuperview() // since we rotate (this is the width)
            make.top.equalTo(regionsLabel.snp.bottom).offset(15)
            make.width.equalTo(100)
        }
 rotationAngle = -90 * (.pi/180)
        regionsPicker.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rotationAngle)
}
```

As can be seen above, I am trying to align the bottom of my label to the top of my picker view. But since I am rotating my view making the height equal to superview it creates this huge space instead.

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44507242/snapkit-and-uilabels-rotation) that suggest the use of autolayout for this specific case, and alternatively, I can use collection view as well, but I am curious to know if there is a SnapKit solution for this and of

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies in this part of the description of transform in Apple's docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622459-transform

> In iOS 8.0 and later, the transform property does not affect Auto Layout. Auto layout calculates a view’s alignment rectangle based on its untransformed frame.
>   So, when you change the text of the label, your constraints are related to the untransformed frame.

So, you are setting the **height** of the pickerView to the **height** of the view. Then you rotate it, and it ***appears*** to look how you want it to look.

If you use `Debug View Hierarchy`, though, you'll see that the pickerView now extends well past the leading and trailing edges of its superView.

You'll also see the width and height of ***bounds*** of the pickerView - `100 x 667` (on an iPhone 8) - which is not what you expected.

This will also present a problem when the view size changes (such as on device rotation).

Here is an example approach:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let regionsLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        v.text = "Testing"
        return v
    }()

    let regionsPicker: UIPickerView = {
        let v = UIPickerView()
        v.backgroundColor = .green
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .cyan

        // add the label
        view.addSubview(regionsLabel)

        // center label horizontally, 10-pts from view top (safe area)
        regionsLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
            make.top.equalTo(self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.top).offset(10)
        }

        // add the picker view
        view.addSubview(regionsPicker)

        // rotate the picker view
        let rotationAngle: CGFloat = -90 * (.pi/180)
        regionsPicker.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rotationAngle)

    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        regionsPicker.snp.remakeConstraints { (make) in

            // constrain picker view center horizontally
            make.centerX.equalToSuperview()

            // constant of 100 - because it's rotated, set the width
            make.width.equalTo(100)

            // constrain the height to a constant equal to the view width
            make.height.equalTo(view.bounds.width)

            // constrain the centerY to the centerY of the label,
            // plus one-half the label's frame height / 2
            // plus a constant of 65 (half the "height" of the picker view + 15-pts spacing)
            make.centerY.equalTo(regionsLabel.snp.centerY).offset(regionsLabel.frame.height / 2.0 + 65.0)

        }

    }

}
```

Which results in:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!